# error :Data-Truncation while inserting in table

Tags: sql, jdbc

i am trying to insert the value in the table by passing the value in a function
like this:

```
public void insert(long r,String s_n,char sex,String sf_n,String sm_n,int c,char sec,long tel,long amount,String add,int age,String house)
    {
        try{
            this.ps=this.con.prepareStatement("insert into s_table values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
            this.ps.setLong(1,r);
            this.ps.setString(2,s_n);
            this.ps.setObject(3,sex,java.sql.Types.CHAR);
            this.ps.setString(4,sf_n);
            this.ps.setString(5,sm_n);
            this.ps.setInt(6,c);
            this.ps.setObject(7,sec,java.sql.Types.CHAR);
            this.ps.setLong(8,tel);
            this.ps.setLong(9,amount);
            this.ps.setString(10,add);
            this.ps.setInt(11, age);
            this.ps.setString(12,house);
            this.ps.executeUpdate();
            this.ps.close();
            con.close();
        }catch(SQLException e){System.out.println("The statement is not established while inserting the element bco'z of "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

the jsp page model is:

but it is showing data truncation error.
[image]FYI:connection has been established

Comment: Data truncation?  Sounds like you're put a value whose size is larger than the columns allotted size.

Comment: Without the database structure and a more descriptive error of which column is beign truncated, it's tough to give you and advice.

Comment: And please add the appropriate tag for your DBMS (Postgres, Oracle, Firebird, ...)

Answer (score -1):

As said in the comments, this must be because of your columns' size.

I think you find a solution and you haven't put your question as "answered" but I think it could be useful for people who can have this problem. So here is my answer.

Here a sql code who can be yours, varchar(x) allow you to have a string of x char without any problem:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
--
-- BDD: `test2`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure of the table `s_table`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `s_table` (
  `r` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s_n` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `sex` int NOT NULL,
  `sf_n` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `sm_n` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `c` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sec` int NOT NULL,
  `tel` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `amount` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `house` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`r`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

If there is anything else just ask.